# Windows 8.1 and fingerprint readers

Tags: security, login, fingerprint, windows-8.1

Is there any build in UI for that kind of hardware like it exist in Modern UI for WiFi, Bluetooth, Broadband mobile and other common settings or I'm forced to use separate software (besides the obvious drivers for hardware)? The thing is that I have build-in fingerprint reader in my laptop and I have installed all necessary official drivers for it (and it looks like they are working fine, btw). But I did not find any UI settings where I could change **Sign-in** option from password/picture password/pin to fingerprint.

Comment: Native supoprt for these types of devices already exists in Windows 8.

Comment: Sounds great! Could you please show some screen shots (or images) how this settings looks like in Modern UI part of the Windows 8.1?

Comment: There isn't a Modern UI interface to my knowlege.  I just simply pointed out there is native support for these devices.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for tip. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this offical driver](http://www.validityinc.com/software/hp/wbf.php) (version 4.5.124.00) for my **Validity VFS491 sensor** (HP Elitebook 8570w). It supports native Windows 8.1 fingerprint enrollment.

Comment: Manythanks erikvdv1! This new driver 4.5.124.00 get fingerprint sign-in back to work for me again, taking into account that the old drivers v4.3.100 I've referred to in my original answer stops working for me in Windows 8.1 RTM (they only worked in Windows 8.1 Preview).

Answer (score 4):

Well, after digging <strike>a while</strike> a lot I've finally managed to make it work on my machine so I guess now I could answer my own question - just in case someone will find it useful.

Firstly - all credits for the solution belong for **Axel Foley** with his awesome post [Quick-guide for Validity fingerprint device drivers and SimplePass software Windows 7 and Windows 8 (only for HP Notebooks)](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-drivers-software-forum/404164-drivers-hp-dv6-2xxx-dv7-3xxx-dv8-hdx16-hdx18-intel-249.html#post8961770)  on *Notebookreview*'s forum.

The trick was (as always) with *specific* driver version (not even close to the latest!). In my case it was [**Validity WBF v4.3.100.0**](http://blackcitrusdesign.com/clients/Validity/news/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/windows_wbf_tek_4_3_100_0_digital_persona_fma.zip) by [Validity](http://www.validityinc.com/). **Note** that the link to the driver is NOT from the official vendor, but from some third-party site (although this link IS from original Axel's post)! So, as always:

**! Use it only on you own risk !**

In short - yes, this was the only thing to do - reinstall driver for fingerprint hardware with just a few reboots between (re-)installation.

For the long answer I recommend to read the original post from Axel.

And finally - the screenshot below was acquired from my **HP EliteBook 2760p** with **VFS471** sensor and **v4.3.100 driver** installed from the link above. So it *may* not work for other configurations.

PS. I believe this setting was there since Windows 8, unfortunately I did not find time to solve this issue with fingerprint until 8.1 preview. But now it is not relevant :)

**Update**: now even [Fingerprint authentication API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182886.aspx#one) started working for me in Windows Store apps.

[image: Modern UI setting]

Comment: The driver file with specific version (v4.3.100) is no longer available on your link. Can you please edit your post with a new link? I am not able to find it. Any version from HP site is not working and the oldest one is newer then yours 4.3.117.0. @user265200

Comment: @Tog thanks for notice - I'll update this post soon with correct link and let you know.

Comment: @Tog please try to use driver **4.5.124.00** from the *erikvdv1* answer - [http://www.validityinc.com/software/hp/wbf.php](http://www.validityinc.com/software/hp/wbf.php) - at least it works for me as for him.

Comment: Thanks, I asked on behalf of @user265200, since I deleted his answer which was asking for that info.

Answer (score 0):

An update for Windows 10 and Validity VFS471 driver installation for Windows Hello feature to work. Tested on HP 6560b notebook (PID=003c).

1. Go to microsoft update catalog: seach for synaptics wbf, get latest 4.5.5XX fingerprint driver for PID=0017 (currently, I'm using version 4.5.516). Link: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=WBF%200017
2. Download CAB file and extract driver (use 7-zip) to some folder on disk
3. Go to device manager -> fingerprint device (VID_138A&PID_003C) -> driver tab -> update driver -> select from PC -> select from List -> uncheck "Show compatible drivers" -> choose "have disk" and point to extracted folder -> select "Synaptics FP Sensors" in the left and then "Synaptics FP Sensors (WBF) (PID=0017)". Proceed with driver installation.
4. In device manager go to properties of device and in energy management untick option "allow computer to turn off this device to save energy"
5. enroll your fingers with Windows Hello